# Pass URL from K8s-ConfigMap to SpringBoot Application

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I'm quite new to Kubernetes and started using MiniKube to experiment with K8s.

### Explanation

This is the (very simple) scenario I want to realize:

1. PrintClient provides a http-endpoint: `<url>/<stringToPrint>`
2. PrintClient redirects `<stringToPrint>` to PrintServer
3. PrintServer just print out `<stringToPrint>` in console

The scenario is meant as a proof-of-concept, and will be the basis for a evaluation in the company I'm working at, therefore it needs to accomplish the following tasks:

- both applications are running inside the MiniKube-cluster
- PrintClient should have an ExternalService
- PrintServer should have an InternalService
- the URL for PrintServer should come from a ConfigMap using
  PrintServer's InternalService

### Code

Here are the relevant files for my scenario.
At first I show you the code of both applications:

**PrintClient**

PrintClientApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PrintClientApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PrintClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Api.java

```
@RestController
public class Api {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate rs;

    @Value("${PRINT_SERVER_URL}")
    private String printServerUrl;

    @GetMapping("/{string}")
    public void print(@PathVariable("string")String string) {
        System.out.println(printServerUrl);
        rs.getForObject( printServerUrl + string, String.class);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
PRINT_SERVER_URL=thisIsJustAPlaceholder
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
COPY /target/print_client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/
ENV PRINT_SERVER_URL=blah
WORKDIR /usr/app/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "print_client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", "PRINT_SERVER_URL=${PRINT_SERVER_URL}"]
```

deployment+service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: print-client-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: print-client-label
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: print-client-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: print-client
          image: patrickshaikh/print_client:1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: PRINT_SERVER_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: print-client-configmap
                  key: print_server_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: print-client-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: print-client-label
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30001
```

configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: print-client-configmap
data:
  print_server_url: print-server-service
```

**PrintServer**

Api.java

```
@RestController
public class Api {
    @GetMapping("/{string}")
    public void hello(@PathVariable("string") String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

deployment+service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: print-server-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: print-server
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: print-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: print-server
          image: patrickshaikh/print_server:1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: print-server-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: print-server
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30000
```

(It is an ExternalService for testing purpose, but will be internal later.)

I already checked if CoreDNS is running:
[image]

### Misbehaviour

1. I used the name of the print-server-service in the ConfigMap but instead of resolving it to an URL before passing the value to the container on initialization, it treats it as a string (during a testiteration I printed the URL to console as well).
2. Using the IP of PrintServers InternalService results in a 404 while using the IP of its ExternalService works flawlessly.

### Questions at answerers

1. Why can't it resolve the reference to the print-server-service to
   its internal IP?
2. What would be the proper way of passing URLs to a container using
   servicenames?
3. Is there anything else in terms of "best practice" in my scenario i
   could adapt?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please explain how are you trying to query the server locally? Are you using the `ClusterIP`?

Comment: currently im querieing the PrintServer using its External Service, but id like to replace it with an Internal Service as soon as the DNS is able to resolve it by the servicename provided in the configmap